# Corrupted jpg file with Esp32-s3 and OV5640 module

Tags: arduino, camera, microcontroller, esp32, arduino-esp32

Summary of the problem: the [Arducam OV5640D module](https://www.arducam.com/product/5-mp-ov5640d-cmos-af-camera-module-1-4-inch-module/), in combination with the ESP32-S3 microcontroller, produces valid images at low resolution, but corrupted ones when set to the maximum resolution.

We have been working with the ESP32-S3 dev module (ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N8R8) in order to capture 5 megapixel images with the Arducam OV5640D (which essentially is, to our understanding, a breakout board with voltage dividers for the OV5640 camera module).

The mcu and the camera module are connected through female-female 20cm long jumper wires.

When setting the resolution to HQVGA (240x176) we get the following output:

```
cESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3808,len:0x44c
load:0x403c9700,len:0xbe4
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2a38
entry 0x403c98d4
[   115][I][esp32-hal-psram.c:96] psramInit(): PSRAM enabled
[   129][D][esp32-s3-minimal-ov5640-test.ino:18] printDebugMemoryInfo(): Total heap: 388856
[   129][D][esp32-s3-minimal-ov5640-test.ino:19] printDebugMemoryInfo(): Free heap: 363272
[   134][D][esp32-s3-minimal-ov5640-test.ino:20] printDebugMemoryInfo(): Total PSRAM: 8386295
[   142][D][esp32-s3-minimal-ov5640-test.ino:21] printDebugMemoryInfo(): Free PSRAM: 8386295
[  1057][I][camera_functions.ino:84] camera_capture(): [camera_functions.ino] Picture taken! Its size was: 1452 bytes
FFD8FFE000104A46494600010101000000000000FFDB0043000C0809
...
00A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2800A2803FFFD9
```

One camera would sometimes give us a broken or corrupted jpeg file, other times a valid one.
Testing with another camera the output seems to be valid.

When setting the resolution to FRAMESIZE_QSXGA 2560x1920 the first camera would sometimes give a "camera capture failed error", other times an output.
The second camera would give a valid jpeg file, albeit corrupted in some way (ie a portion of the image appears shifted or with abnormal colors).

This is the code:

main Arduino file

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  printDebugMemoryInfo();
  camera_init();
}

void loop()
{  
  camera_capture();
  delay(5000);
}

void printDebugMemoryInfo()
{
  log_d("Total heap: %d", ESP.getHeapSize());
  log_d("Free heap: %d", ESP.getFreeHeap());
  log_d("Total PSRAM: %d", ESP.getPsramSize());
  log_d("Free PSRAM: %d", ESP.getFreePsram());
}
```

second arduino file (camera_functions.ino):

```cpp
#include "esp_camera.h"


#define CAM_MODULE_NAME "Arducam OV5640D"
#define CAM_PIN_PWDN -1
#define CAM_PIN_RESET -1

#define CAM_PIN_VSYNC 12
#define CAM_PIN_HREF 11
#define CAM_PIN_PCLK 10
#define CAM_PIN_XCLK 9

#define XCLK_FREQ_HZ 20000000

#define CAM_PIN_SIOD 13 //sda
#define CAM_PIN_SIOC 8 //scl

#define CAM_PIN_D0 4
#define CAM_PIN_D1 5
#define CAM_PIN_D2 6
#define CAM_PIN_D3 7
#define CAM_PIN_D4 15
#define CAM_PIN_D5 16
#define CAM_PIN_D6 17
#define CAM_PIN_D7 18

static const char* TAG = "camera_functions.ino";

static camera_config_t camera_config = {  
  .pin_pwdn = CAM_PIN_PWDN,
  .pin_reset = CAM_PIN_RESET,
  .pin_xclk = CAM_PIN_XCLK,
  .pin_sscb_sda = CAM_PIN_SIOD,
  .pin_sscb_scl = CAM_PIN_SIOC,

  .pin_d7 = CAM_PIN_D7,
  .pin_d6 = CAM_PIN_D6,
  .pin_d5 = CAM_PIN_D5,
  .pin_d4 = CAM_PIN_D4,
  .pin_d3 = CAM_PIN_D3,
  .pin_d2 = CAM_PIN_D2,
  .pin_d1 = CAM_PIN_D1,
  .pin_d0 = CAM_PIN_D0,
  .pin_vsync = CAM_PIN_VSYNC,
  .pin_href = CAM_PIN_HREF,
  .pin_pclk = CAM_PIN_PCLK,

  .xclk_freq_hz = XCLK_FREQ_HZ,
  .ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0,
  .ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0,

  .pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG,
  .frame_size = FRAMESIZE_HQVGA, //240x176
  .jpeg_quality = 12,
  .fb_count = 1,
  .grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST//CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY
};

esp_err_t camera_init(){
  //power up the camera if PWDN pin is defined
  if(CAM_PIN_PWDN != -1){
    pinMode(CAM_PIN_PWDN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(CAM_PIN_PWDN, LOW);
  }

  //initialize the camera
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&camera_config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Camera Init Failed");
    return err;
  }

  return ESP_OK;
}

esp_err_t camera_capture(){
  //acquire a frame
  camera_fb_t * fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Camera Capture Failed");
    return ESP_FAIL;
  }
    
  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Picture taken! Its size was: %zu bytes", fb->len);
  for (int i=0; i<fb->len; i++) {
    if (fb->buf[i] < 16) {
      Serial.print('0');
    }
    Serial.print(fb->buf[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();

  //return the frame buffer back to the driver for reuse
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
  return ESP_OK;
}
```

[Arduino config menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQmf0.png)

[corrupted low resolution image example from the first (allegedly defective) camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJUZi.jpg)

[corrupted high resolution image example from the second (allegedly better) camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKmmI.jpg)

I have checked the wiring again and again, and tested it with a multimeter for continuity.
It appears to be stable, however I don't know if the length or the connection may cause some interference.

As stated above I have separately tested two controller boards and two camera modules.

I have found [this comment](https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/issues/150#issuecomment-726473652) on an issue providing some possible solutions to the problem.
These are:

- checking if each buffer contains a valid jpg image
- tricking the library into initializing with a larger buffer, then changing the jpeg compression to produce a smaller file
  The first solution basically throws away most of the images (as stated by the author).
  The second solution seems like a workaround and could be problematic in case the [esp-camera library](https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera) got an update.